# Blazor Localization

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I try to implement localization in Blazor application but I encounter some issues when try to get the resource value by key in the view.

How I can achieve this?

Here is my code so far:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization(options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
        options =>
        {
            List<CultureInfo> supportedCultures =
                new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("bg-BG"),
                    new CultureInfo("en-US")
                };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("bg-BG");

            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;

            // UI string 
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

        });

    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; });

    services.AddApplicationRepositoryServices();

    services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
     app.UseRequestLocalization( app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
   }

   app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {            
       endpoints.MapRazorPages();

       endpoints.MapBlazorHub();

        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });
}
```

---

**Login.razor**

```
@page "/login"

@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization

@inject IStringLocalizer<Login> Localizer

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">@Localizer["LoginButtonText"]</button>
```

---

**Page location**

Project

-- Pages

---- Account

------ Login.razor

---

**Resource files location**

Project

-- Resources

---- Pages

------ Account

-------- Login.bg-BG.resx

Comment: take a look at this lib - https://github.com/Blazored/Localisation.  discalimer - no idea if this is any good but is mentioned in:  https://github.com/AdrienTorris/awesome-blazor

Comment: This document describes how to localize Blazor applications  https://www.soluling.com/Help/Blazor/Index.htm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me:

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
  services.AddLocalization(options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
  ...
}
```

**Index.razor**

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.Globalization

<h1>Localization test</h1>

Localized field: @(localizer["Field1"])

@code {
    [Inject] public Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer<Index> localizer { get; set; }
}
```

My `resx` files are stored like this:

```
Resources\Pages\Index.resx
Resources\Pages\Index.cs.resx
...
```

[image]

Then, depending on the UICulture, the correct localized string is returned when calling `localizer["Field1"]`.

In the code, I change the UICulture this way:

```cs
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ");
```

Comment: Any idea how I can use the `IStringLocalizer<T>` with satellite assemblies which provides the localization?

Comment: You can also add `@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer<Index> Localizer` to the razor head. The important thing for me was to store it at the correct Resources folder. I forgot the Pages subfolder.

Comment: CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ");  this one did it for me. Thank you!