# Localize blazor with IStringLocalizer using a unique resource file per language

Tags: localization, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to localize my Blazor app (.NET 5.0) using `IStringLocalizer` and user UI selection based on cookies. Following [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#provide-ui-to-choose-the-culture), it seems to work if I create a `.resx` file for each page in my `Resources/Pages` folder.

I'd like to group all key-value pairs within a single file as follows :

```
MyApp
|-- Resources
|       MyResources.resx        <--- set to public modifiers to generate class!!!
|       MyResources.es.resx
|       MyResources.fr.resx
...
|-- Resources
|       Index.razor
```

So in `Startup.cs` I register the `Resources` folder:

```
services.AddControllers();
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

I also added `MapControllers` in the configure method, as well as registering supported cultures. I also added the controller:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class CultureController : Controller {
    public IActionResult SetCulture(string culture, string redirectUri) {
        if (culture != null) {
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)));
        }

        return LocalRedirect(redirectUri);
    }
}
```

Now, on my main "index.razor" page I inject the `IStringLocalizer<MyResources>` as follows:

```
@page "/index"
@inject IStringLocalizer<Language> _localizer

<h2>@_localizer["hello_world"]</h2>
<h2>@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()</h2>
<h2>@DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()</h2>
```

I make sure that all `resx` files actually contain the "hello_world" key with some values and added a language selector.

When I run the app, changing the language does change the displayed dates, however, the `hello_world` key is not found so the app displays the key instead. When exploring the `_localizer` variable, I see that the container is empty - none of the key-value pairs of the `.resx` are actually loaded.

Is it possible to get this to work? If so, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is because of naming here:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<Language> _localizer
```

should be

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<MyResources> _localizer
```

And important is to add an empty file `MyResources.razor` at the root of the project.

Edit:
Another mistake I made is to add the `myApp.Resources` to `_Imports.razor`

```
...
@using myApp.Resources    <==== do NOT add this
```

Answer (score 2):

@neggenbe
Adding an empty razor(AppLang.razor) component at the root of my project with same name with my resource(AppLang.resx) file solved the challenge. I stumbled accross @neggenbe after over 48 hours trying to figure out what was wrong with my code.

If your project is purely blazor, you wont come accross this challenge but if its a mix of MVC and razor(blazor) components, then you'll definately need to do this.